# Tailwind Default color is white instead of black how to change this

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm working with Tailwind CSS and I want to modify the default text color without specifying the text utility classes throughout my project. Is there a way to globally change the default text color directly within Tailwind CSS without having to add the text-color classes to individual elements?

I've explored the Tailwind CSS documentation and tried configuring the theme but couldn't find a straightforward way to change the default text color without explicitly setting the text utility classes everywhere. I'd like to know if there's a more centralized and efficient way to modify the default text color in Tailwind CSS.

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
 /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
       
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the theme object, you can define or modify the colors as needed. To change the default text color, you can set the colors property within the theme object.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // Change the default text color to your desired color
        'text-default': '#333333', // Replace '#333333' with your preferred color code
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

After defining the new color in the colors object (in this case named 'text-default'), you can apply it globally without needing to specify individual utility classes by using the text-text-default class in your HTML elements. This modification will set the default text color for the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do it in your Tailwind CSS file?

For example, in your index.css (or whatever name you called your Tailwind's input CSS file), you can do something like this:

```
// main.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html {
  @apply text-gray-500;
}
```

This approach will apply Tailwind's `text-gray-600` class to all textual element in the HTML document by default. You can also pass any arbitrary color here. E.g

```
html {
  @apply text-[#5B21B6]; // shade of purple
}
```

I hope this helps you!